# SYSLINUX? Booting off a Live USB?

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, installation

I used Unetbootin to install Xubuntu to a Live USB (a 4 GB SanDisk). By default, I'm running Windows 7 (which is also what I ran Unetbootin on). The computer I'm trying to use to boot off the Live USB is an HP Pavilion g7 (also runs Windows 7 by default). I also configured the Live USB to have 1250 MB of persistent storage.

I've rearranged the boot order to immediately start with the USB, and I've also tried directly booting off the USB.

No matter what I do, I get the message:

> SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al

However, nothing happens past that. What should I do?

*There are no messages past the one I posted, its all there is on the screen, plus my blinking underscore cursor on the line directly beneath the message