# How do I remove the extra Ubuntu option on the Windows Boot Manager menu?

Tags: wubi

I installed ubuntu using Wubi side by side with Windows. I decided to uninstall ubuntu and install Kubuntu, which I did successfully. However now when I boot my computer, the Windows Boot Manager displays 3 options:

- Windows
- Ubuntu
- Kubuntu

The Ubuntu option does not work, but the entry did not get removed when I uninstalled  Ubuntu the first time. How do i get rid of this extra entry?

Comment: Did you try running "sudo update-grub"?

Answer (score 9):

For Windows Vista, 7 or 8, run `bcdedit` as an administrator (hit Windows key, type `cmd`, look above and right-click `CMD.EXE` and select `Run as administrator`).

This will list the Windows Boot Manager entries:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {1476af5e-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
displayorder            {current}
                        {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 10

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {1476af60-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {1476af5e-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
nx                      OptIn

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
description             Ubuntu

C:\windows\system32>
```

Note the `Real-mode Boot Sector` entry that has a description of `Ubuntu`. Copy and paste the `identifier` and then delete it as follows (in my case):

```
bcdedit /delete {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
```

For Windows XP, you can edit `C:\boot.ini`. I recommend making a backup first as an error can prevent Windows from booting. Also you should edit it as follows:

1. Right-click `My Computer`, and then click `Properties`.
2. On the `Advanced` tab, click `Settings`under `Startup and Recovery`.
3. Under `System Startup` click `Edit`.
4. Delete the line `C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"`

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>bcdedit.exe
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The system cannot find the file specified. -- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. :\

Comment: @Kobie, see this: http://askubuntu.com/q/73585/14916

Comment: This method also works in Windows 10, FYI

Comment: This method works perfectly for other operating systems in the Real-mode Boot Sector (Remix OS in my case)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer), a graphical grub2 settings manager.