# Ubuntu launch option on startup remains

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I used windows installer to install Ubuntu and it was getting errors on bootup. Well that didn't work, I guess I'll try and boot from a USB to install it. However, after messing around with uninstalling (aka deleting Ubuntu folder after booting into Win7) I cannot get rid of the launch option.

There is nothing in Computer Management because I never actually booted into Ubuntu to create space on my HDD for the OS. I can't just uninstall using Program and Features in Control Panel (because I already deleted the folder)

Now everytime I boot up it gives me the options of booting into Windows 7 or Ubuntu, how do I disable this page/get rid of the Ubuntu launch option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu

Comment: @user68186 I'm not sure this is a duplicate of that, because while they're both Wubi systems, here it doesn't seem like Ubuntu was ever really *uninstalled*.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a Wubi system--that is, that you installed Ubuntu while booted into Windows.

If that is the case, you should be able to remove Ubuntu, including the selection for Ubuntu in the Windows boot menu (that comes up when you start your computer), by going to Add/Remove Programs (in the Control Panel, in Windows), and removing Ubuntu.

If you've **already** uninstalled Ubuntu and it worked, except that you still get to "choose" between Windows and Ubuntu when you start up, then this question, which @user68186 found, should help you:

- [How do I remove the extra Ubuntu option on the Windows Boot Manager menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu)

If you find you're **unable** to uninstall Ubuntu in Add/Remove Programs, you got errors when you tried to do so, or it never appeared in Add/Remove Programs, then you can [manually uninstall it as explained in this section of the Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F).