# Wubi Installed Twice (without uninstalling the first), now I can't remove the second

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the extra Ubuntu option on the Windows Boot Manager menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu)

Wubi Installed Twice (without uninstalling the first), now I can't remove the second

---

So, I uninstalled Ubuntu from Program Files on Windows 8. But, I originally installed Ubuntu twice accidentally. Wubi didn't uninstall completely, so Windows 8's boot manager is telling me that I still can boot into Ubuntu even though I have deleted all files (I think) that Wubi installed. What can I do to remove or fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the Windows Boot Manager showing two Ubuntu entries? If so refer to this: http://askubuntu.com/q/145444/14916