# When i start my laptop i have a choice of three ubuntu operating systems how can i remove this?

Tags: boot

Only 1 works and the other 2 don't.I want to get rid of these other 2, also the Ubuntu i am running on now I want it to be the only operating system as i also got windows 7. Is there anyway i can do this with using a CD.

Comment: startup the working ubuntu run `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did a wubi install, where you install inside the windows file system.  To fix the problem try the answer(s) on [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu)

To install Ubuntu as the only operating  system you would need to use the bootable LiveCD and and boot off it to replace the operating system.  Make sure you back up all your important data before you do this as you will be starting from scratch with the "use entire hard drive" option.