# Removing duplicate entries in boot menu (WUBI)

Tags: wubi

I tried a Wubi install, but it got stuck, so I restarted the system, uninstalled it from Windows and did the whole process again. Now, in the menu that shows Windows 7 and Ubuntu as options, there are 2 Ubuntu options. How do I trim it?

Comment: What boot manager are you using - GRUB2 or the windows boot manager?

Comment: If you installed with Wubi, it will use thw Windows boot manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove the extra Ubuntu option on the Windows Boot Manager menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Windows install, edit `C:\boot.ini`.  Remove the old entry/line, and you're done!

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, I think there's no boot.ini file anymore. But I'm accepting the answer since it's right on WinXP, and I found bcdedit.exe for Win7.

Comment: Wait but it the comment below you said you edited it?

Comment: Ah whatever.  Glad your problem is solved!

Comment: Ah okay! Good (I probably should have recommended that XD)!