# How to remove my first Ubuntu because my computer has two Ubuntus

Tags: uninstall

My computer has three operating systems: Windows 7 and two Ubuntu 13.10. 
Trying to explain: First of all, when I bought this computer, a Dell Inspiron, Windows 7 was incorporated. 
Some years later I downloaded the image 13.04 from www.ubuntu.com; as per its instructions I burned the iso on a dvd. By means of the BIOS the machine starts by the disk before the hard disk. Then, actually, when starting the computer appears a GRUB and anybody can choose either Ubuntu or Windows 7. Certainly Ubuntu was upgraded into 13.10.
From www.ubuntu.cat I roughly did the same procedure but in Windows 7 I may select Windows or Ubuntu (wubi).
At this point I would like to remove the first Ubuntu.
How to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear but you may look at [this question on how to uninstall ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Bon dia! I am not sure if I understood correctly, but maybe the answers on this question on [how to remove entries in the boot menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227903/removing-duplicate-entries-in-boot-menu-wubi) provide additional information.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't worry**, follow my instructions.

---

***IMPORTANT NOTE***: I **suggest** you to remove Ubuntu (Wubi) and not the real Ubuntu installation, because **the real Ubuntu installation will always be faster**: Ubuntu (Wubi) is installed as a Windows software and can be removed like any Windows application, from the Control Panel (if you remove Wubi you will lose any data saved in the Wubi virtual partition).

---

***INSTRUCTIONS***: To remove permanently the real Ubuntu installation with all its data, enter in the Ubuntu (Wubi) installation and with a partition software like `gParted` delete the real Ubuntu partition; you can also use a live DVD/CD with any distro installed to do the procedure.
You can execute `Gparted Partition Editor` from *System -> Administration* in Ubuntu systems **or** use the apposite `gParted live CD` (a safer alternative) by following [this official guide (CLICK!)](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual#gparted-live-booting-gparted-live).
After that reboot and test your in-use systems at least two times.

***SUGGESTION***: If you format the deleted partition's space with NTFS you'll be able to re-use it in both Windows & Linux (Linux will need extra support drivers & wrappers).

Click the up arrow if I'm of any help and feel free to comment down here if you need more help,

have a nice day. :-)

Comment: Hello Lorenzo, I could find this text: sudo apt-get install gparted and I am unable to find out any gParted in Ubuntu-wubi. Do you think the above sentence on the Terminal of the real Ubuntu could be remove it?

Comment: Simply install gParted does nothing, you must use it. If you can't find gparted, install it from your preferred packet manager or run directly "sudo apt-get install gparted" from any virtual terminal (xterm is fine): this will install gparted. You'll be able to start it later, like I said, from System -> Administration or from the console directly. Installing gParted on the real Ubuntu is useless, because it will be erased like any other partition's content: install & use it from Wubi's Ubuntu, the system that you want to preserve. Hope I'm clear, if I don't, insert another comment. :)

Comment: I have followed your instructions.
On the new Terminal Xtrim the orders were as you selected:
sudo apt-get install gparted. 
Result: lack of permissions !, access denied, /var/ is locked.
I don't find System -> Administration and on the System Settings all the above do not appear.

Comment: I didn't write of the system settings, but of GParted: it will appear in the menu when you will manage to install it correctly, don't worry. I don't know the exact output of your try but I suggest you to read this sudo explanation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo 
How to configure sudo: http://www.royhochstenbach.com/configuring-sudo-the-proper-way/  
In short: restart your system, check if sudo is configured correctly (read the link, if you inserted YOUR current user password and, if all fails, enable the root account and use it.