# How to access previous ubuntu wubi installation

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, wubi

I installed ubuntu/wubi nearly a year ago on my windows 8 pc. It has been sitting on a separate partition untouched since then. I am trying to access it again as I'd like to use Ubuntu now. I cannot figure out how to boot to Ubuntu. When I go to `msconfig" -> boot`. I only see an option for Windows.

The Ubuntu file hierarchy looks like this:

```
D:\ -> ubuntu -> disks, install, winboot
```

The disk file root.disk is about 18gb.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I will be at a hotel for over a month and my connection will cutout if I try to reinstall via wubi since it's an 18gb download.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1. Install Ubuntu via Wubi on your main partition.
2. Find the Ubuntu install in Program Files or Program Files (x86) on the installation Wubi was installed on before reading this
3. Copy the root (/) directory and all its contents to your new Wubi install.
4. Profit!

Alternatively, you can mount the partition with Wubi in it and make a shortcut to its launcher on the old partition.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I will be at a hotel for over a month and my connection will cutout if I try to reinstall via wubi since it's an 18gb download.

Comment: Try the process at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an entry to your Windows BCD store so that you get a choice to boot into Ubuntu from the *Windows Boot Manager*. First open a command prompt as an administrator (right click on `CMD.EXE` and select `Run as administrator`).

Then:

```
bcdedit /create /d Ubuntu /application bootsector
```

This creates an entry for Ubuntu and returns the {GUID}, but doesn't do anything yet. Note the GUID that is returned and use it in place of `xxx-xxx-xxx` in the following commands:

```
bcdedit /set {xxx-xxx-xxx} device partition=D:
bcdedit /set {xxx-xxx-xxx} path \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
bcdedit /displayorder {xxx-xxx-xxx} /addlast
bcdedit /timeout 10
```

After that you will get the option to boot into either Windows or Ubuntu when you boot.

One last thing... make sure there is a `C:\wubildr` file, or else you will need to copy `D:\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr` to `C:\wubildr`

PS... since you are adding this entry manually, it won't be automatically removed by uninstalling Wubi. You can delete it as described here: [askubuntu.com/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu/145605#145605)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am happy to say that I am responding to you from my ubuntu partition. I was astonished that it actually worked. I'd vote your answer up, but I don't have the reputation yet to do so.

Comment: @pandeee Yeah it does seem astonishing, doesn't it ;) But that's exactly what `wubi.exe` does when you install Ubuntu. Anyway - since you created the question you should be able to click on the tick to accept the answer (even without upvoting). Enjoy!