# Problem with loading ubuntu 12.04 aftrer reinstalling windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation, wubi

I installed windows 7. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi.exe and after I REinstalled Widows 7 I couldn't load Ubuntu. I downloaded and installed "EasyBCD 2.2" and made new entry with "Type: GRUB 2 ;" and "Drive: Automatically locate and load" and after restart when chose Ubuntu i saw black screen waiting for command with text "grub> " how to fix it to show me normal ubuntu 12.04 screen? 
Thanks!

*I tried and with wubi in EasyBCD and it was the same...*

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/314393/how-to-access-previous-ubuntu-wubi-installation

Comment: When you install Ubuntu with wubi the Ubuntu filesystem is actually stored in a file on your Windows NTFS drive, not a partition. (see the link from bcbc above). Depending on how you reinstalled windows you may (or may not) have lost that file.

Answer (score 0):

[RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

This is a problem between GRUB and MBR. Simply, GRUB can detect MBR but MBR can miss GRUB when Windows is installed after Linux. And it is easy to be fixed! All you need to do is configuring MBR and GRUB again via your Ubuntu installation dics. I mean not installing again; only a session as Live user and it is done.
You may want to see this link, everything is explained clearly here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

**:)**