# boot removed after installing windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, wubi

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on my computer (D:\ or sda2) via Wubi installer, but recently I have removed my windows and installed windows 8 instead and that removed the option to boot to Ubuntu.
I tried to use the boot repair live CD and the grub tool too but it was no good, please I looked for many solution and none of them worked I really need help.

Thanks

Comment: This explains it: http://askubuntu.com/a/314487/14916

Comment: @bcbc oh thank you so much, finally hours of frustrations are over.

Answer (score 1):

There are many utilities you can use with the install media.
BCDBOOT or BCDEDIT or mbrfix are just a few examples.

Note that Wubi is considered deprecated ; the official method to install is to use the official iso file.

Also which OS does not boot?

**If you want to fix ubuntu** then use its live version and in `gparted` flag ubuntu partition as boot

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `gparted` and not `gpirated`.

Comment: @belacqua yes of course

Comment: @user251046 tried it, ((bootmgr is missing press ctrl+alt+del to restart))

Answer (score 1):

Windows installer is not compatible with Windows 8 or UEFI firmware, and is not available for Ubuntu 13.10. as stated on official [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) page.

You can use a [general method for dual booting Windows 7/8 and Linux versions on MBR disks](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html).

The method uses a Windows boot sector loader for chain loading grub/grub2.

So you simply add a new boot sector loader to Windows BCD and give it as parameter a file which is a copy of first stage of GRUB2 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get around this is to insert a bootable disk or usb like you are going to do a fresh install. You'll want to start up to the live desktop, open a terminal, and enter the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Once it is all done installing, it will launch and you should be able to get it to work with just the recommended repair. If that doesn't want to work for you when you reboot, follow the same steps and then go into the advanced options and you can select the options to reinstall grub, select what OS to boot from, where to place the reinstall of grub, etc.

Note: you have to do this through the ubuntu live desktop from a bootable disk or usb. Do, not reinstall ubuntu or anything like that when you boot into the live session. Just enter that code into the terminal and you should be all good.

Comment: as I said on the original post, i tried using boot repair and it failed, the OS to boot by default is blank and there is no option to reinstall grub

Comment: If you are still able to boot into Windows 8, you could always try running Linux reader to see if your install of Ubuntu is even still present on your machine. Go to http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/ and give it a try. If there are any Linux partitions on your drive, it will find them and let you browse through them in Windows Explorer. If you don't see anything after running Linux Reader, it's highly likely that the install of Windows 8 completely wiped your hard drive at the beginning of it's installation process.