# Ubuntu 12.04 installed via Wubi failed to boot problem

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, wubi

I downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file from the internet and I mounted the ISO image via daemon tool and ran the wubi.exe to install Ubuntu on a newly partitioned hard drive in Windows 7. It installed successfully but when I reboot the laptop. I got the following error below. Now I was just curious and wanted to see what Ubuntu would look like. However, I was able to start window normally, so I logged onto my Window account and immediately format the hard drive with Ubuntu installed and appended the disk space to my original hard drive. I restarted the laptop again. I got the same error.

I have read many threads of this sort. But they all require a inserting Window installation disc, which I don't have. What should I do ?

I am a very nontechnical person and I don't understand any Linux/Unix stuff and this is why I don't understand much from those similar threads. I just want to remove Ubuntu completely from my laptop now. I also want to ask does "startup repair" remove everything in my laptop?

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."  
 3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance. 

 File: \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
 Status: 0xc0000000e
 Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: You should have uninstalled with the control panel. But now you will have to remove the boot entry using this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu

Answer (score 0):

From a terminal on the LiveCD/USB (Applications > Accessories > Terminal), run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

This assumes that sda is the Windows drive. If not, change this to reflect the actual drive e.g. sdb, sdc, etc.

Ignore any warnings and continue with the installation to the MBR. The main point is to get lilo installed and allow the user to boot Windows, and hopefully Ubuntu, again.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198

---

edit: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F

Comment: Sorry, Since I can log onto Window fine, can I just type those "sudo" command lines on Applications > Accessories > Terminal without using LiveCD / USB ?? I just want to be safe since I have no idea what command lines mean

Comment: i edited my answer; try the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Please, **don't use Wubi**. **Wubi is not longer supported** nor a safe method to install Ubuntu. For uninstalling Wubi:

- Boot into your windows installation
- Go to Control Panel > All Programs
- Then look for Ubuntu and uninstall it.
- Restart your system with the Ubuntu CD inside your CD/DVD-ROM
- Make sure your BIOS is set to boot from the CD-ROM first (consult your manual)
- You will have a screen asking if you want to "Try Ubuntu without installing" hit enter.

Now you can test Ubuntu without touching your Hard Disk, if you want to install it at any point click "Install Ubuntu".