# Help Uninstalling Ubuntu from Windows 7, both on same drive

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi, uninstall

I have seen a couple guides that spoke about uninstalling ubuntu and have tried following the guides provided in AskUbuntu.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS from an usb drive and have chosen to install it on same drive/partition.

I then have tried to remove ubuntu first under the windows uninstall programs screen. The ubuntu logo was on there, however when I clicked on it to install it errored out and states that this program is not available. After that the icon disappeared.

After that I did a search on the C drive for ubuntu items and folders and saw the wubi uninstalled. I ran that program, and if finished successfully. However, when I restarted my laptop the ubuntu start-up menu still appeared and asked if I wanted to run either ubuntu or windows partition like earlier.

Is it possible to completely remove Ubuntu from Windows 7 using an ubuntu usb stick (same process that I used to install Ubuntu side by side with Windows 7) and if I can would that affect windows 7.

Also I have seen OS-Uninstaller mentioned in some of the other guides. Would that be risky if you are trying to remove Ubuntu OS while also logged into Ubuntu OS?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is easier (doesn't require a Windows install disc or repair prompt): http://askubuntu.com/q/145444/14916

Answer (score 0):

Try using EasyBCD. Use EasyBCD to delete the Ubuntu Entry. Ubuntu recently messed up my Uefi boot on my system and i wont be trying it anymore.

Comment: Hi Timi owoturo,

I have downloaded and installed EasyBCD and from the boot menu only Win7 is seen as the default. But when I restart my computer, Ubuntu menu is still coming up and asking me to select either windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To restore the Windows bootloader you will need your Windows 7 installation disc and follow these: [instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).  After doing that you should expect to boot right into Windows without a GRUB prompt.  Since you installed using WUBI that should be all you need to do.  If you had installed Ubuntu to its own partition then you would use the: [disk partition](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-manage-your-disks-using-disk-management-utility) tool to reclaim the space after fixing the bootloader.  Since you used WUBI that step is not necessary however.

Edit: you already used the WUBI uninstaller so the files on your Windows drive are gone, with that done then the above instructions just complete the uninstall.

Comment: Just "/fixmbr" and "/fixboot" in the first link instructions is all you have to do.

Comment: And if you don't have a Windows 7 installation disc but instead have OEM media then be very careful, OEM media usually doesn't have the full tools and might boot right into installing 7 and erasing what's on the drive right now.

Comment: A note to future googlers: once you fixed the bootloader then in the disk partition tool, you would delete the Ubuntu/Linux partition and then merge that free space into your Windows partition to complete uninstalling any Ubuntu/Linux system.