# Unable to install Ubuntu

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi Installer Error: The boot configuration data store could not be opened](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73585/wubi-installer-error-the-boot-configuration-data-store-could-not-be-opened)

I'm unable to install Ubuntu using Windows Installer. I get the following error message.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCOQP.jpg

Comment: Have you tried with another `ISO` file?

Comment: In the right window it is written that there is more information in the log file `c:\users\harish\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.10-rev273.log`. Is it possible to see what is written in this file ?