# Installing with Wubi - cannot edit BCD error

Tags: installation, boot, windows, wubi

Everything download and installs and right before the installation is finished I get an error and it says something about BCD, I think Wubi cannot set the bootsectors properly but why is that? I tried so many times...

I just want to be able to choose between Win7 and Ubuntu when booting my PC

The Error:
Error executing command

```
command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {45b546de-fc69-11e1-82db-c95eae63f03e} device partition=U:
retval=1
stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
```

The request is not supported.

```
stdout=
```

Comment: What does it say about BCD? The error message content is important. You can find it without reinstalling in the logfile in the `%TEMP%` directory name `wubi-xx.xx-revxxx.log`.

Comment: Is it this?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73585/wubi-installer-error-the-boot-configuration-data-store-could-not-be-opened