# Removing Ubuntu, Please Help

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, uninstall

I had the wubi.exe in my 16gb usb drive. When attempting to install it, I mistakenly selected my USB drive as my installation drive. After installing, I formatted my USB drive, meaning the uninstaller is gone.

Current problem:

-Now my PC asks for choosing an operating system between Windows 8 and Ubuntu where the Ubuntu does not work.

-I am trying to get rid of that Ubuntu without affecting my Windows 8.

-From Windows 8, System Configuration>Boot, it only shows Windows 8 (No Ubuntu), so I can't even delete it.

-I used EasyBCD 2.2 which does not list any OS. (I think my windows 8 is installed on my 24GB SSD)

-Most internet solutions says to delete the partition which contains Ubuntu. But I selected USB drive at the first place which is not a partition.

-Since my USB is formatted, it should not have Ubuntu. Yet, regardless of if the USB drive is connected, when I restart my computer, it displays OS choosing screen which lists Windows 8 and Ubuntu. How do I get rid of that Ubuntu?

Please help me. I really do not want to factory reset my laptop.

Comment: Factory resetting won't help anyway (often the boot partition is not included in the reset). Use this [How do I remove the extra Ubuntu option on the Windows Boot Manager menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145444/how-do-i-remove-the-extra-ubuntu-option-on-the-windows-boot-manager-menu/145605#145605) instead. But that's doing what easyBCD does so you might have to check this out: http://askubuntu.com/q/73585/14916 if you can't open the BCD datastore.

Comment: Quite a few details are unclear from your description, and any answer that makes a wrong assumption about these details will be unhelpful or even make matters worse. I recommend you run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates to a pastebin site, and post the URL here. That will give us the information we need to provide a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. removing the identifier worked. Now my laptop boots up really quick just like before.

Comment: please put that in the answer box and mark it as solved to clean up one more question with no upvoted answers so the people who need attention can get it