# Impossible to run Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, wubi, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi Installer Error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73585/wubi-installer-error)

I've been trying for a while to run Ubuntu, but nothing I do seems to work (outside of a virtual machine, and I'd really rather not run it in a virtual machine).

I've tried using Wubi to install it, but I get an error ([see the post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73585/wubi-installer-error)) and I've tried to install it to a Live USB ([see the post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72696/syslinux-booting-off-a-live-usb)) but nobody has been able to help me with either of those two problems, and I've asked on multiple websites.

Am I just doomed to fail? I really want to run Ubuntu without completely removing Windows. Is there any other options? What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has an optical drive (or you have an external optical drive that connects to your computer through an interface such as USB from which it can boot), you can install by burning the installation CD .iso image to a CD or DVD and booting from that. You could try using the alternate .iso rather than the desktop .iso, though that seems that it would be unlikely to help, considering how early in the boot process the error occurs.

Besides that, you can try the specific suggestions I've posted in the two questions themselves.